# Class probability in binary classification with sigmoid output

Tags: keras

I'm doing binary classification with keras and my last layer is:

`predictions = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', activation='sigmoid')(x)`

I'd like to know if the output/score of my model is in a 1:1 correspondence with the class 1 probability.

i.e.

```
>>> model.predict(X)
0.67
```

means that X has a 67% probability to belong to class 1 and 1-67%=33% probability to belong to class 0.

I know that higher score means higher class 1 probability, but I do not know if the correspondence is linear.

Thanks